# Creating a 'sub-screen', similar to how watch behaves

Tags: python, csh, watch

I have a Python script which generates a lot of different text outputs that require me to clear the screen quite regularly. The problem with this is that once the script is finished, I have a terminal full of junk that I no longer need. I could just clear the terminal, but I'd prefer to have a behaviour similar to what happens when you 'watch' a command.

Watch makes it's own kind of 'sub-screen', and once you kill it you're returned to the terminal with all the displayed output from your command cleared away and your previous commands shown in the terminal. I think this is much cleaner.

Is there any way to achieve this? I'm using C shell if it's relevant but I could just as easily use bash or some other shell.

Comment: Related: [Show output on another “screen” and return to normal when done](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27941/show-output-on-another-screen-and-return-to-normal-when-done)

Answer (score 0):

Credit to ilkkachu for finding this

I solved the problem using the answer to this question (I've linked it below):

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/27951/270784